# UISearchDisplayController and UISearchBar in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I'm trying to create a `UITableViewController` in a storyboard with a `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController`.

I also want to use the `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` property of the `UISearchDisplayController`.

However, no matter what I do it is messing up the display of the table.

I was initially following this tutorial by [AppCode](http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/) but it doesn't use the navigation bar property.

Anyway, I stripped down the code to an absolute minimum that still fails.

You can see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/oliverfoggin/10024117).

When I run it it leaves a "ghost" search bar in the table. Like this...

[image]

This happens whether I push onto the current navigation controller or present with a new nag controller. Nothing works.

Storyboard on request...

[image: Storyboard screenshot]

It is just a plain UITableView subclass with a default style cell and and search bar. I haven't added anything else. (You can do the same following the AppCoda tutorial above). All I have added is the `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` code.

The two ways I have tried loading this.

First. As a modal view controller.

```
- (IBAction)userSearch
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"UserSearch" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *controller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Second. As a standard push.

```
- (IBAction)userSearch
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"UserSearch" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UINavigationController *controller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller.topViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I know this isn't the standard way to push a view controller using a nag controller I just wanted to check it wasn't the modal present. I am using a separate storyboard as there will potentially be a user flow through this. Also I tried a standard nib and that didn't work either.

Tried to code the `UISearchDisplayController` manually by overriding `- (UISearchDisplayController *)searchDisplayController` on the `UITableViewController` and that did the same thing.

**Screenshots after moving the UISearchBar in the Storyboard navigator panel**

[image: No BG Color]

[image: Weird gap]

[image: Another weird gap]

Comment: could you show the storyboard also please ?

Comment: @James03 will do. just uploading now.

Comment: move the `search bar` below `Search Display Controller` and let me know, I think, I don't know how but it seems like it has duplicate the search bar object

Comment: ah maybe, look at the `outlets` of your `Search Display Controller`, does he has the right `outlets` ?

Comment: @James03 yeah, all the outlets are set. Just trying to mess around having put the search bar under the display controller. It has half worked.

Comment: `It has half worked`, how that ? could you edit your question ?

Comment: @James03 there is no background to the search bar and it goes a bit odd when editing it. Uploading screenshots now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @James03 ok, new screenshots up. Thanks again